# No session currently bound to execution context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, dropwizard

I got below exception when I used `session.getCurrentSession()`.

I have mentioned

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class: managed

org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext.currentSession(ManagedSessionContext.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.AbstractDAO.currentSession(AbstractDAO.java:36)
    at io.dropwizard.hibernate.AbstractDAO.persist(AbstractDAO.java:149)
```

I use this with `dropwizard`. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Code you please provide the code which throws the exception

Comment: Initially I wrote Query for getting the information from DB. This will executed. But after that I used to save the data into the other tables. It gives an error. I thought session will be closed after execute the my first DB interaction. But this should be expected as I use hibernate.current_session_context_class: managed

Comment: Code will be too long to paste hear

Comment: you run in application class and configuration of your HibernateBundle at least so we could help

Comment: I think the best approach here is to open and close the session for each action.

Comment: How are you declaring your session, show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 65):

If you are using Dropwizard Hibernate. You need to add `@UnitOfWork` annotation to your Resource method. More info within [dropwizard manual, *hibernate chapter*](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/hibernate.html).

Comment: The best answer

Comment: Working link: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/hibernate.html

Comment: Thanks @MetalMichael I've updated the link in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Can you try with : `session.openSession()` - It tell hibernate to always opens a new session and you have to close once you are done with the operations. With `session.getCurrentSession()`, hibernate returns a session bound to a context that you don't need to close and only need to set the hibernate.current_session_context_class to thread.

You can also configure session with `SpringSessionContext`, if your application is Spring based.

Edit your **`hibernate-cfg.xml`** with below line:

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext
```

**What above line will do?**

Making session context class as **"org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext
"**, Hibernate will assume it is executing inside of a Spring transactional context (i.e. through a Spring transactional aspect) and Spring will now manage your transaction for you. However if you call `getCurrentSession()` outside of such a context, Hibernate will throw an exception complaining that no Session is bound to the thread.